# Parse.com iOS SDK 1.7.1 logInController didFailToLogInWithError returns user unfriendly Error Message

Tags: authentication, parse-platform, ios8, passwords

### iOS8, Parse 1.7.1 SDK and Xcode 6.3

**logInController didFailToLogInWithError: returns cryptic error message when wrong username/password is entered**

logInController didFailToLogInWithError: is returning an error message for wrong username and password that is not very user friendly (see attached image). Is this a new behavior under Parse 1.7.1? I don't recall seeing this message with earlier versions of Parse but maybe I've just not noticed it before.

Is there a way to override this message with something more user friendly or is there something else happening here that I am not understanding?

[image: logInController didFailToLogInWithError:]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is an issue with the new ParseUI. Looking at the ParseUI source on GitHub, the issue is with the following code:

```
- (void)_loginDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (_delegateExistingMethods.didFailToLogIn) {
    [_delegate logInViewController:self didFailToLogInWithError:error];
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PFLogInFailureNotification object:self];

NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"Login Error", @"Login error alert title in PFLogInViewController");
[PFUIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:title error:error];
```

}

The last line (`[PFUIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:title error:error];`) is what cannot be overridden. The only way to truly change this is to get the ParseUI code from the [GitHub](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS) repo, remove that line, and compile your own version of the library. Then you can override the `logInViewController didFailToLogInWithError` method to show your own custom error. See the code below as an example of how to throw your own message.

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didFailToLogInWithError error: NSError?) {

    var errorInfo = error?.userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject]?
    var errorMessage = errorInfo!["error"] as! String

    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Failed", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    logInController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in [Parse UI version 1.1.4](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/releases/tag/1.1.4).  You can see the code changes [here in github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/commit/81e55973af26e1d3303bba1f0b6abb72661e7bab).

```
- (void)_loginDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (_delegateExistingMethods.didFailToLogIn) {
        [_delegate logInViewController:self didFailToLogInWithError:error];
    } else {
        NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"Login Failed", @"Login failed alert title in PFLogInViewController");
        NSString *message = nil;
        if (error.code == kPFErrorObjectNotFound) {
            message = NSLocalizedString(@"The username and password you entered don't match", @"Invalid login credentials alert message in PFLogInViewController");
        } else {
            message = NSLocalizedString(@"Please try again", @"Generic login failed alert message in PFLogInViewController");
        }
        [PFUIAlertView showAlertViewWithTitle:title message:message];
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PFLogInFailureNotification object:self];
}
```